# Write encrypted wstring to wofstream

Tags: c++, encryption, wstring, widechar, wofstream

I have a simple "encryption" function that works with `wstring` variables and I want to write the result of this function into a file, using `wofstream`.

This is my code:

```
void save_file() {
    wstring text = L"Text to be encrypted. The text is encrypted but not saved";
    wstring enctext = encrypt(text);

    wprintf_s(L"%s\n", enctext);
    wofstream output_stream;
    output_stream.open(L"myfile.enc");
    output_stream<< enctext ;
    output_stream.close();
}

wstring encrypt(wstring decrypted) {
    wstring encrypted;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<decrypted.length(); i++) {
        encrypted += wchar_t(int(decrypted[i]) + 128);
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

So, the problem with this piece of ... code is that although the `wprintf_s` function outputs the entire encrypted text, in the written file I only see the characters inside the *ASCII* range (or at least is what it seems to me). The encrypted text is saved until an unknown character is found (displayed by **?** in the console). I want to save any character, and I want them saved as wide chars (1 word each one). How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `fwrite()` or the iostream equivalent to write binary data. `fprintf()` and eqivalents are for text (as in readable text, not binary).